# Sticking flexbox elements to each side of container (one element to the left, the other to the right)

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, flexbox, angular-material

I know this is a very basic question but i can't accomplish what i want.

**Background**

I'm building an Angular 7 application with Angular Material (v7) components.

In Material Card titles, like this ones:

[image]

[image]

**Objective**

I want the icons to stick to the right, and the text to stick to the left. So, whatever the element's width is, they are sticked to each side.

BUT, I need the text able to use the remaining space if needed. For example:

```
|-----container (mat-card-title)-----|
|Short title-------------------|icons|
|A longer title----------------|icons|
|A muuuuuuuuch longer title----|icons|

|----------very large container (mat-card-title)-------------|
|Short title-------------------------------------------|icons|
|A longer title in a large container-------------------|icons|
|A muuuuuch longer title in a veeeery large container--|icons|
```

Also, I want both icons (button elements) to stick side-by-side if a break is needed because of an small width.

**So far**

I've tried several things, coming up to this flexbox styles to the **mat-card-title** element

```
mat-card-title {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}
```

And then, inline:

```
<mat-card-title>
  <div style="flex: 2 1 auto">
    <span>Latest Messages ({{count}})</span>
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1; justify-self: flex-end; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: end; 
              flex-wrap: nowrap">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</mat-card-title>
```

**Question**

**Is this approach ok? How can i accomplish my objective?**

Let me know if I should provide more information

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the inline styles and make it a class so it's cleaner. It should look something like this:

```
mat-card-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

.buttons {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 0.2; //note you can also just specify a width in percentage, this is like setting a width of 20% (or however wide the buttons are)
}

<mat-card-title>
  <div>
    <span>Latest Messages ({{count}})</span>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</mat-card-title>
```

Good luck!